# In Elisp how to dynamically assign value to a variable which also selected dynamically (in let form.)

Tags: lisp, elisp

I have a alist of known variables and corresponding functions with nil parameter list, inside body it use that known non-parameter (or global) variable.

for e.g.

```
(defun funA ()
  (message "%s" varA))

(defun funB ()
  (message "%s" varB))

...

(setq alist
      '((varA . funA)
        (varB . funB)
        ...
        ))
```

Similar element in alist can be added / deleted dynamically.

I want to run all these function in another function where the value of known variable assigned dynamically in LET form.

```
(defun call-each-fun-of-alist ()
  (dolist (e alist)
    (let (( (car e)  (read-from-minibuffer "value: ") ))
      (funcall (cdr e)))))
```

(Yes it will throw error, but I wanted to similar thing, possible without EVAL)

For known element of alist (like first I could do

```
(let ((varA (read-from-minibuffer "value: ")))
  (funcall (cdr (assoc 'varA alist))))
```

But alist is dynamically updated and I what to run all functions in alist
and the value for corresponding variable will come dynamically.

Please let me know how I can define

```
call-each-fun-of-alist
```

(not necessarily but without calling EVAL inside call-each-fun-of-alist, if not possible without EVAL than I like to know it also.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with `letf` (`cl-letf` in recent Emacs). It binds values like `let` but allows 'places' or 'generalized variables' as well as simple variable names.

```
(defun call-each-fun-of-alist ()
  (cl-dolist (e alist)
    (cl-destructuring-bind (variable . function) e
      (cl-letf (((symbol-value variable)
                 (read-from-minibuffer
                  (format "value for %s: "
                          variable))))
        (funcall function)))))
```

Note that this will fail with an error unless the variables named in `alist` have previously been declared as dynamic variables using `defvar`. Look up 'generalized variables' in the Elisp manual for more information.

Another solution would be to use `cl-progv`, which takes parallel lists of variable names and values to bind dynamically:

```
(defun call-each-fun-of-alist ()
  (cl-dolist (e alist)
    (cl-destructuring-bind (variable . function) e
      (cl-progv
          (list variable)
          (list (read-from-minibuffer
                 (format "value for %s: "
                         variable)))
        (funcall function)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Common Lisp this is provided by `PROGV` - dynamic binding of a variable given the symbol of the variable.

GNU Emacs should have `PROGV` in its Common Lisp emulation.

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need -- no need for `progv` or destructing bind stuff:

```
(defun call-each-fun-of-alist (alist)
  (dolist (e  alist)
    (set (car e) (read-from-minibuffer "value: "))
    (funcall (cdr e))))

(defvar my-alist '((varA . funA) (varB . funB)))
(call-each-fun-of-alist my-alist)
```

Or if you really want to see a `let` binding for some reason:

```
(defun call-each-fun-of-alist (alist)
  (dolist (e  alist)
    (eval `(let ((,(car e)  (read-from-minibuffer "value: ")))
             (funcall (cdr e))))))
```